# Is there a way to loop over a function with changing inputs and union all the results?

Tags: sql, postgresql, function, for-loop, union-all

I have a function that returns product information in a table. I would like to query this function results for different products and aggregate the responses. What's the best way to do it?
So far I have approached like this, but I am hoping there's a way to loop over a function, giving a list of products as an input:

```
SELECT name, key, value
FROM infofunc_v1('whitepasta')
UNION ALL
SELECT name, key, value
FROM infofunc_v1('darkpasta')
```

First post in Stack. Grateful for all advice, have a nice day!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a lateral join:

```
SELECT name, key, value
FROM (VALUES ('whitepasta'), ('darkpasta')) v(val) CROSS JOIN LATERAL
     infofunc_v1('whitepasta');
```

Note:  If you want a single input parameter, the `VALUES` can be `UNNEST(:array)`, so you can pass in an array of values.

Comment: Thanks for the fast reply! 

With your example I get a syntax error at the end of input. Any ideas why that could occur? 

Same with:
FROM (VALUES (UNNEST(:array))) v(val) JOIN LATERAL infofunc_v1('whitepasta');

:(

Comment: @M2R10 . . . Here is a db<>fiddle with a simplified function:  https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=e8ef84c1f4484e391f0d872ca01e7424.

Comment: I believe cross join did the trick. Thanks alot!

Comment: @M2R10 . . . LOL.  A `JOIN` needs an `ON` clause.  The issue had nothing to do with function calls, arrays, or anything like that.